# How does a computer know the difference between numbers and letters in binary?

Tags: encoding, binary, computer-science

01000001 can be an integer (65), or a letter, (“A”). A computer doesn’t know a thing - it’s just a blob of binary. And everything in a computer is represented in binary, so how does it distinguish a letter from a number?

So when you have a .txt file that contains this text and you want to read it how does it know if it should be interpreted as 65 or as letter A? If 01000001 (65) is assigned to be “A” then what if you meant 65?

```
I have 65 animals
```

It is not

```
I have A animals
```

So when the computer program is processing this file and it comes across 01000001 - how does it know if it is A animals or 65 animals? If it is the same binary data?

Also when using text to binary converters it says that A is 01000001 but 65 is 00110110 00110101 - why is that?

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question in the last portion of your post.

Comment: @RyanWilson can you explain? Wasn't 65 supposed to be 01000001 ?

Comment: Maybe this post will help you (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547090/how-do-machines-interpret-binary)

Answer (score 0):

In ASCII The letter A is mapped to the number 65 which in binary is 01000001. But when you are using text to binary converter and type 65, the converter views 65 as 6 and 5 as two separate numbers and in ASCII 6 is mapped to 54 which is 0110110 in binary and 5 is mapped to 53 which is 0110101 in binary.

Now coming back to your original question of how does a computer know the difference between binary numbers and letters, A computer knows when to use binary numbers or ASCII based on the context and the specific operations being performed. The distinction between the two is typically determined by the software and the data type being processed. so when you type 65 in the text to binary converter it view that in ASCII thus showing you 00110110 00110101.